# what is the notation of nonlinear transformation of vector

Tags: algebra-precalculus, notation

Suppose $y = (y_1, \dots, y_n)$ is a vector, how to express the relation, take logarithm $\log{y_i}$ or $y_i^r$ to each element, just $\log y$ and $y^r$ is Ok?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: Since what you seem to want to do is pretty non-standard and highly restricted (all the vector's entries must be positive for you take logarithm on them...), you better just say in the proper cases: take the logarithms of all the vector's entries.